# In the Java class DecimalFormat, what do the hashtags at the left side of the decimal do?

Tags: java, class, formatting, format, decimalformat

My title of this question I have isn't so great, but hopefully I can explain it more in this post.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.text.*;
public class Output {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    /*double number = 438.978;
    /*UpperCase <- naming convention for classes.DecimalFormat x = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
    System.out.println(x.format(number));*/

    double number = 43.97;
    DecimalFormat x = new DecimalFormat(".###");
    System.out.println(x.format(number));

  }
}
```

Don't mind the comments. During my Gr 11 Comp Sci class I asked my teacher if the hashtags on the left of the decimal point(*11th line*) did anything to the double number, we tried it as a class and we found that it did not change the output of the *System.out.println* statement.

```
~/workspace/Java/ $ java Output
43.97
```

Can someone explain to me the purpose of the parameters to the left of the decimal? Someone programmed it to do something so I was just curious.

Comment: The hashes show optional digits. try formatting `3.14159265`

Comment: Unless I'm wrong, which is possible, the question is about a format like *`##.###`* where there are parameters to the ***left*** of the `.`, answers so far have only answered what it means in general.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like others have said `#` formats a digit but drops zeros.

In your example where you apply `.###` to a double like `12.34` it *would* format to `12.340` but since it drops zeros it does not.

The same happens when you put a `#` **before** the decimal, for example `###.###` to format `12.34` *would* display `012.340` but since it drops zeros it displays as `12.34`.

So a `#` **before** the decimal will really do nothing.

An example of something useful **before** the decimal, so you can see formats before the decimal *can* work is `0` which formats a digit but does **not** drop zeros, and can also be used in the DecimalFormat. A pattern like `000.000` applied to `12.34` results in `012.340`:

```
double d = 12.34;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("000.000");
System.out.print(df.format(d));
```

Patterns like `0`, `#` and more are defined in [DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would have just been happy with you telling me that the hashtags before the decimal does not do anything practical, but you showed me a case of this working with 0's. Never knew I could do that with this class.

Answer (score 0):

`#` formats a digit, but drops zeros. Since your number has two digits after the decimal, the third format character is ignored. If you had a number with four digits after the decimal point, they would have been reduced to three significant digits.

Comment: Unless I'm wrong which is also possible, the question is about what parameters to the **left** of the decimal will do, not what `#` means in general.

Answer (score 0):

As per [DecimalFormat docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) `#` is used to conditionally show the digit.

```
Symbol  Location    Localized?  Meaning
#       Number      Yes         Digit, zero shows as absent
```

Do note that the number of `#` used matters:

```
DecimalFormat x = new DecimalFormat(".###");
System.out.println(x.format(43.9711111)); // 43.971
```

Comment: Unless I'm wrong which is also possible, the question is about what parameters to the **left** of the decimal will do, not what `#` means in general.

Comment: I know what the hashtags to the right of the decimal point do, I was asking what the decimal points to the left do.

Comment: @SamuelQuansah Please see my answer which covers `#` to the left of the decimal point.

Comment: @Mark will do, was only able to take a quick look since I was in school.